# double for loops in R for histograms

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following table and I am trying to run a double for loop in R to get a histogram of the distribution of responses for every month of the survey (I will then fit a distribution to it). I am currently running the following code, but cannot seem to get anywhere. Any suggestions?

`for (i in 2008:2021) { for (j in 1:12) { dfn <- df(df$Year=i, df$Month=j) hist(dfn) }}`

| Month | Year | `-3` | `0` | `2` | `4` | `5.5` | `8` | `12.5` | `15` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2008 | 3 | 2 | 28 | 41 | 17 | 3 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 2008 | 5 | 3 | 26 | 40 | 15 | 4 | 6 | 1 |
| 3 | 2008 | 6 | 4 | 27 | 39 | 13 | 4 | 6 | 1 |
| 4 | 2008 | 9 | 4 | 18 | 28 | 28 | 5 | 7 | 1 |
| 5 | 2008 | 6 | 5 | 15 | 29 | 29 | 6 | 9 | 1 |
| 6 | 2008 | 8 | 3 | 17 | 28 | 26 | 6 | 10 | 2 |
| 7 | 2008 | 9 | 5 | 16 | 28 | 28 | 4 | 9 | 1 |
| 8 | 2008 | 5 | 5 | 19 | 29 | 26 | 5 | 9 | 2 |
| 9 | 2008 | 7 | 5 | 22 | 39 | 15 | 4 | 7 | 1 |
| 10 | 2008 | 8 | 6 | 20 | 40 | 15 | 4 | 7 | 0 |

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to understand how to ask a good question (providing data, more code and context, and what not). Good questions are more likely to get good answers :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.